# Getting text to appear after image not beside it (In CSS or HTML)

Tags: html, css, image

I am using a website template to create a web page. I want to add some images then add text below the image. However each time I try to add text, it keeps adding the text beside the image instead of below the image.

I have tried to seperate the images using the tags below but none have worked

This is what the code looks like now

```html
<p>
<img src="https://www.planetware.com/wpimages/2020/02/france-in-pictures-beautiful-places-to-photograph-eiffel-tower.jpg" width="522" />
          </p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  </p>
          <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
          <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
          <h2>1988  cup
```

[Image and text on the same line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R04TA.jpg)

Comment: where is your css?

Answer (score 1):

- Wrap your image and caption in a `div`
- Set that `div` to the width you want that section to be.
- Change the width on the image to `100%` instead of `522px`

```css
.image-container {
  max-width: 522px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <p>
     <img src="https://www.planetware.com/wpimages/2020/02/france-in-pictures-beautiful-places-to-photograph-eiffel-tower.jpg" width="100%;" />
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  </p>
  <h2>1988 cup</h2>
</div>
```